# Models are see through in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

this is something that's been bothering me for a while and i've yet to find a solution.

sometimes when i'm editing a model the object is transparent in edit mode, i do not have wire turned on in display and limit selection is off.

Have tried to change face in preferences > theme but no luck. Also tried to change my clipping and it didn't help.

Is this a bug or am i missing something obvious?

Thanks.

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable this button ("Limit selection to visible")

[image]

Also, you must setup more usefull limits here:

[image]

The result of "End"/"Start" mast be as low as it possible. Now you have `299621/0.000001=296210000000` - it is very big! Increase the first value and reduce the second, so that the result of the division becomes less than million.

Comment: i've tried that, doesn't work,

Comment: Can you provide blend file?

Comment: @KevinDoan I've updated the post

Comment: @KevinDoan  This looks exactly like a clipping problem.  Adjusting clipping distance should fix it.  Don't use 0.000001 ever.   0.1 or 0.01 is good enough.  Float precision is the culprit.

Comment: Clipping was correct, specifically making sure the ratio was right. Thanks.